# Can't get discord.js to play a song with ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so, i tried doing a ytdl thing with discord.js. i get an error saying

> (node:6796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined".

this is where the bot is supposed to play something. ((yes ytdl is defined))

```
const dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(args[1]))
.on("end", () => { 
    console.log("song end");
})
.on("error", () => {
    console.error(error); 
});
```

Comment: The value of `ytdl(args[1])` is undefined (as the error tells you).

Comment: What is the value of `args[1]`? Can you show us how you build the `args` object?

Answer (score 0):

That essentially means "Nothing is there for 'url' or the parameter of `ytdl()`. You should check if it's null or not.

Answer (score 0):

try implementing this function:

```
function Play(connection, message)
{
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(YTDL(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
    server.queue.shift();
    server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
        if(server.queue[0])
        {
            Play(connection, message);
        }
        else
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    });

}
```

This essentially means that when the function is run, itll create a queue of songs and play them in order. When no songs are left, it will disconnect from the voice channel.

Comment: note that before using this function you should use `server.queue.push(args)` where *args* is the youtube video link